# customize ng-bootstrap carousel?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize ng-bootstrap Carousel in a way that each slide will come from the bottom and that won't be auto slide change. The slides suppose to come with some animation.
Another thing that I want to do is that the slide will change on mouse scroll.
I'm using angular 6.

Here is the code I have:

```html
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images"> 
    <ng-template ngbSlide> 
        <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide"> 
        <div class="carousel-caption"> 
           <h3>10 seconds between slides...</h3> 
               <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p> 
        </div> 
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: it's the example in their site: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>10 seconds between slides...</h3>
      <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let consider the 3 things you want to do in turn...

**1. Animate so slides come from the bottom**

For this, you can add the following CSS to your component that houses the `ngb-carousel`:

```
::ng-deep .carousel-item {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition:all  1s;
}

::ng-deep .carousel-item.active {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}
```

You should be able to tweak the CSS until you get the exact animation you want.

**Warning:** Angular is planning to deprecate `/deep/`, `>>>`, and `::ng-deep`, however you should be able to use `::ng-deep` for the time being:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

source: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

**2. Disable automatic changing of slides**

Set the `interval` property of `ngb-carousel` to `false` - this is usually a numeric value (number of milliseconds to keep each slide on show), but setting it to `false` will disable the automatic slideshow.

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" [interval]="false" #carousel></ngb-carousel>
```

**3. Change slide on mouse scroll**

Add the following `@HostListener` in your component. This listens for the mouse scroll event and will execute the code within the `scroll()` function when it detects the event. The code below load the previous slide if you scroll down, and the next slide if you scroll up. Change `event.wheelDelta < 0` to `event.wheelDelta > 0` if you want it the other way round.

```
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event'])
  scroll() { 
    if (event.wheelDelta < 0) {
      this.carousel.prev();
    } else {
      this.carousel.next();
    }
  }
```

To get this to work, you will need to declare the `ngb-carousel` as a variable so you can access it in the Typescript in order to call `next()` and `prev()`:

**HTML**

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" [interval]="false" #carousel>
```

**Typescript**

```
@ViewChild('carousel')
carousel: any;
```

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjinkw?file=app%2Fcarousel-basic.ts) for a working demo.

Comment: `[interval]="false"` now produces this error: `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'`

Comment: does `[interval]="0"` or `[interval]="-1"` work?

Comment: How can I do this without using ::ng-deep?